# Google Apps Script function and arrayformula isn't giving desired output

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In the `column B`, the formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4:A="","",((A4:A-A3:A)/A3:A)*100))` works as expected. So I thought the same arrayformula would work on other formulas as well but in `column C` the formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4:A="","",IF(ROW(A4)<B1+3,0,IF(ROW(A4)=B1+3,AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A, ROW(A4)-(B1-1)):INDEX(A:A,ROW(A4))),IF(ROW(A4)>B1+3,AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A, ROW(A4)-(B1-1)):INDEX(A:A,ROW(A4))))))))
```

doesn't give the expected output, however it still expands upto `row 4375`.

And in the column D, I used a google app script function which was only because my formula in `column C` didn't give the expected result but the function below expands way more than `row 4375` when i actually want it to expand only till `row 4375` :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  ss.getRange("D4").setFormula("IF(ROW(A4)<$B$1+3,0,IF(ROW(A4)=$B$1+3,AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A, ROW(A4)-($B$1-1)):INDEX(A:A,ROW(A4))),IF(ROW(A4)>$B$1+3,AVERAGE(INDEX(A:A, ROW(A4)-($B$1-1)):INDEX(A:A,ROW(A4))))))");

  var lr=ss.getLastRow();
  var filldown= ss.getRange(4,4,lr-4);
  ss.getRange("D4").copyTo(filldown);
}
```

However it gives the expected output upto `row 4375`

What am i doing wrong in the formula in `column C` and the function for the `column D`?

Here's the link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TFf6XO2aIiphIJC3Wp9Bx9Lr6X6R9AevyssdOLeDCcg/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: The number of rows should lastrow-startrow+1

Comment: @Cooper Are you saying in the function ``ss.getRange(4,4,lr-4+1)``? it's not working either. if it's  possible, can you ask for permissions from the link, maybe you can directly work work on the sheets?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow links to spreadsheets.  All the information required in your question should be posted in your question.

Comment: `the formula doesn't give the expected output` Can you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo and @Cooper what i'm trying to achieve is a simple moving average calculated dynamically as the size of the list grows in `col A`. However in `col C` i get '0' all the way down to the last row after i wrap it inside `arrayformula`. If i don't wrap it in `arrayformula`, the result will be correct but i'll have to manually pull to autofill. In `col D` however the result is dynamically generated from the function (as i want it in `col C` as well) but it doesn't stop at the lastrow which is non-empty. it fills the entire sheet

Comment: Please can you make your sheet editable? I can not create a copy in its current state

Comment: @RafaGuillermo it's editable now. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: I found the answer to one of the problem on why the function was expanding beyond the last row. The function as it turns out works perfectly fine if we removed the ``arrayformula`` part because the function reads last row as literally the last row because ``arrayformula`` expanded till the last row ``A4:A`` even though it seems like it's only filled upto ``row 4375`` and the function reads the last value as the last row in the sheet because of the ``:A`` part. Regarding the ``arrayformula`` in ``col C`` part. I still don't know.